# Dealing with possible mental health issues

Tags: mental-health

I do some volunteer work for a Hacker Space, if you aren't familiar with what that is its just a place with shared tools where people can come to work on projects and occasionally collaborate with other people.

We are open to the general public free of charge, we only ask that people, while they are there to treat everyone else with respect. The place where we operate has a lot of homeless people and other people that are suffering from general mental health issues. Many of these people have various conspiracy theories, ex: The government is watching us, or we're being bombarded with rays that are giving us all cancer, or similar... we generally just nod and ignore them... But there is one individual who has been coming in frequently who has these very strange and elaborate theories about how we all are being mind-controlled and something about strings inhabiting our bodies that we can't see.... its hard to go into full detail, but its generally presented in a very consistent yet extremely weird way... The guy is generally very nice to talk to and mostly just keeps to himself, silently working on "art" (or propaganda) related to his theories.

My question is where does this cross a line into something we should contact some official mental health professional?

What free services could we use to help get an assessment and how likely would it be that someone like this would turn violent?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a workplace issue, but something you should talk to a social worker or mental health expert to.

Comment: If you think someone is a danger to themselves or others, that's when you contact the police and let them deal with it. That's the threshold.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie noting that in many parts of the world, police are not well trained to deal with mental health emergencies without using lethal force, so this is something that should only be done if there's a clear and present danger. Nothing in OP's post suggests that this guy has violent tendencies.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Then, unless they are violating the rules of the space, they should be left alone.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is where does this cross a line into something we should
>   contact some official mental health professional?
>
> What free services could we use to help get an assessment and how
>   likely would it be that someone like this would turn violent?

Tread carefully here. It doesn't sound like it's within your purvey to offer mental health services to clients.

That said, contact a local public health organization to see what they could suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a legal duty to inform anyone about this sort of thing. With that out of the way, you can consider your options. Do keep in mind that people like this are usually aware of themselves and their struggles. Your intervention probably won't help the person very much.

- do nothing. That is a very viable course of action.
- if a client is **repeatedly disruptive**, or uses **street drugs** in the bathroom, or **threatens** the safety of himself or others, you can tell him he must **leave**, and he's **not welcome** in your space. This takes a lot of fortitude. He'll try to argue with you. Don't join the argument: just keep saying, "you're not welcome here." For best results, make sure somebody else (coworker, friend) is present and knows you're doing this.
- if he returns after being asked to leave, then you should ask for help from the police.

I've had to tell somebody to leave a couple of times. It's a tough deal. But you owe it to yourself and the people around you to do it in a firm way.

Comment: I would just say that before evicting people, it's important to have very clear policies in place regarding acceptable behaviour. While it may be obvious to most people that certain behaviours are unacceptable, we are dealing with people whose realities are a little different from our own, so we can't take for granted they understand what is acceptable without being told.